# Степень членимости слов?

Tags: словообразование

Блюдце, загадка, вонзить, заповедь, издать, именинник, ящик, огурец

Comment: Степень членимости - это разделение на слоги или перенос? Что имеется в виду?

Comment: сопоставимость по корневым и аффиксальным рядам

Comment: О степени членимости здесь http://www.portal-slovo.ru/philology/37384.php

Answer (score 1):

Блюдце, загадка, издать, именинник – 1-й степени членимости. Заповедь, по-видимому, 4-й. Ящик и огурец – 5-й. Но могу и ошибаться, проверяйте. :) Кстати, метка выставлена неправильно. Вопрос относится не к морфологии, а к словообразованию.